# Generic allocator error when trying to place lambda function on queue (probably something related to unique_ptr)

Tags: c++

I'm getting those generic C++ allocator errors when trying to put a lambda function in a queue. I guess it's probably related to the `unique_ptr` inside my class `Buffer`.

I know that when I add a `unique_ptr` I make it such that the class cannot be copied because `unique_ptr` deletes its copy constructor. However I can copy it to the inside of the lambda function (don't know how). The problem seems to appear only when I try to copy the lamdba function itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
typedef std::function<void()> Task;
std::queue<Task> tasks;

template <class T>
    class Buffer final
    {
    public:
        static Buffer fromOwned(T buffer, size_t size)
        {
            return Buffer(std::make_unique<T>(buffer), size);
        }

        Buffer(std::unique_ptr<T> buffer, size_t size)
        {
            _buffer = std::move(buffer);
            _size = size;
        }
        size_t size() {
            return _size;
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<T> _buffer;
        size_t _size = 0;
    };

int main()
{
  auto b = Buffer<uint8_t*>::fromOwned(new uint8_t[1], 1);
  auto f = [b]() mutable {
      b.size();
  };
  tasks.emplace(f);
}
```

Error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:34:12: error: use of deleted function 'Buffer<unsigned char*>::Buffer(const Buffer<unsigned char*>&)'

   34 |   auto f = [b]() mutable {

      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   35 |       b.size();

      |       ~~~~~~~~~

   36 |   };

      |   ~         

<source>:10:11: note: 'Buffer<unsigned char*>::Buffer(const Buffer<unsigned char*>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

   10 |     class Buffer final

      |           ^~~~~~

<source>:10:11: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = unsigned char*; _Dp = std::default_delete<unsigned char*>]'

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20200709/include/c++/11.0.0/memory:83,

                 from <source>:3:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20200709/include/c++/11.0.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:468:7: note: declared here

  468 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

      |       ^~~~~~~~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

I tried reading the `new_allocator.h` file but it does not tell me anything about the error, which is very generic. Why this is happening? And does somebody have a tip for reading these ultra generic errors?

I tried adding copy and copy assignment to the class:

```
        Buffer(Buffer &buffer) : _size(buffer._size),
        {
            _buffer = std::move(buffer._buffer);
        }

        
        Buffer &operator=(Buffer & buffer) 
        {
            _size = buffer._size;
            _buffer = std::move(buffer._buffer);
        }
```

in the hope that it wouldn't rely on the copy constructor of the `unique_ptr` but it didn't change nothing.

Comment: But `Buffer` isn't a callable object? How is it compatible with the type `Task`?

Comment: Why do you think that you "can copy it to the inside of the lambda function", when the error message points to exactly the place where you try to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a move in the capture, assuming you are using C++14 or earlier:

```
[b = std::move(b)]() mutable {
    b.size();
}
```

Now to the details... First, the error you get is when the compiler tries to build your lambda capture, *NOT* when the lambda gets copied. Since `Buffer`'s copy constructor is deleted (because of the `unique_ptr` member), you cannot copy your `Buffer` object.

You could solve that by implementing a copy constructor, however your implementation is not sound because the "copy" steals the ownership of the object. You should actually copy the buffer:

```
Buffer( const Buffer& other )
    : _size( other._size )
    , _buffer( std::make_unique< T >( *other._buffer ) ) // <- rely on the copy constructor of `T`
{
}

Buffer& operator=( Buffer other )
{
    _size = other._size;
    _buffer = std::move( other._buffer );

    return *this; // <- you forgot this.
}
```

You can however keep the defaulted move semantics:

```
Buffer( Buffer&& other ) = default;
```

With those definitions you will be able to capture by value.

Comment: Is it possible that can solve this using copy constructors? In a way that I do not require to use `std::move`?

Comment: What's the difference between my copy constructor and yours?

Comment: Why do you use `*other.` instead of `other.` in only in the copy constructor? And what's the difference between relying on the copy constructor of `T`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs. In your case there is only one allocated `unique_ptr` that you move from `other` to `this`. Semantically, this is not a copy, it's a move. In my case, I allocate a new object of type `T` that I construct by copy using the content of `other._buffer`